# unable to insert array value from form into single row in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, html

In my app I have one text box.I want to store that text box data in mysql database as an array in single row.That text box number comes from a dropdown in previous page.

```
<form method="post" action="qtableadddb.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php
if(isset($_POST['num'])){
$num=$_POST['num'];
for ($i=1; $i <=$num ; $i++) {
echo "<tr>
<td><label>OPTION " . $i . "</label></td>
<td><input class='form-control' name='txtoptname[]'></td>
<td></td><td></td>
</tr>";
}
}
?>
<tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=6><button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" >ADD QUESTION NO. 1</button></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

**qtableadddb.php**

```
if(isset($_POST["txtoptname"]) && is_array($_POST["txtoptname"])){  
$capture_field_vals ="";
foreach($_POST["txtoptname"] as $key => $text_field){
    $c=("INSERT INTO `accountstable`(`atableid`, `acctableid`, `option1`, `option2`, `option3`, `option4`, `option5`, `option6`, `option7`, `status`) VALUES ('$qno','$i',UPPER('$text_field'),0)");
    mysqli_query($conn,$c) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

I want if three text box data comes then three data insert into mysql database column option1,option2 and option3 and rest of column blank.As my code all data inserted in different row.
Please help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi can you try this one

```
VALUES ('$qno','$i',UPPER('$text_field'),0); convert to 


VALUES ($qno,$i,UPPER($text_field),0);
```

Comment: if(isset($_POST["txtoptname"]) && is_array($_POST["txtoptname"])){   print_r($_POST);  are you getting value here

Comment: yes.But how to insert that array value in database?